# Chrome extension - how to access local file:// with manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I have a Chrome extension that can (if you allow access to file URLs) grab your local pdf file that you have open in chrome and send it on to our API for processing. This is done by fetching the pdf with `XMLHttpRequest` to `file:///Users/user/whatever/testfile.pdf` from the background script.

When migrating to manifest v3 for a Chrome extension the background script becomes a service worker. In a service worker only `fetch` is available, not `XMLHttpRequest`. Problem is, fetch only supports http and https, not file:// urls. So how can I make the same feature of having the Chrome extension fetching/getting the local file?

EDIT: Things I also tried:

1. Making the XMLHttpRequest from injected iframe as suggested by answer.
   This gives error `net:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` when making the request
   [image: net:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME]
2. Making the XMLHttpRequest from injected content script.
   This gives error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///.../testfile1.docx.pdf' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.`
   [image: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/clara.attermo/Downloads/testfile1.docx.pdf' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.]

**From what I can understand from a lot of research access to `file://` is in general blocked and Chrome extension background scripts used to be an exception to this. Seems to me it was never allowed from content scripts or action popups.**

My manifest.json for reference:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "..",
  "version": "0.1",
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon-16x16.png",
    "48": "assets/icon-48x48.png",
    "128": "assets/icon-128x128.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_title": ".."
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "identity",
    "pageCapture"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
    "resources": ["iframe.html"],
    "matches": [],
    "extension_ids": []
  }]
}
```

The content script is injected programmatically (using `webextension-polyfill` for promise support)

```js
browser.action.onClicked.addListener(async (tab: Tab) => {
  await browser.scripting.executeScript({files: [ "inject.js" ], target: {tabId: tab.id}});
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome 98 and older can't do it in the background service worker for the reasons you mentioned.

There was also a [bug](https://crbug.com/1179732) that prevented doing it in a normal visible `chrome-extension://` page or iframe. It's fixed in Chrome 91.

#### Solution

Use `fetch` in Chrome [99 and newer](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commit/268e65004215716c3957b229794357da23acaf2d).
In older versions use the following workarounds.

#### Workaround 1: File System API, Chrome 86+

A ManifestV3 extension can use the new [File System API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/) to read the contents of the file, for example inside the iframe exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/).

#### Workaround 2. Extension frame, Chrome 91+

Use a content script that runs in the tab with that pdf:

1. `matches` in manifest.json should contain `<all_urls>` or `file://*/*` and file access should be enabled by the user in
   chrome://extensions UI for your extension. Alternatively you can use
   `activeTab` permission and [programmatic injection](https://crbug.com/1179732) when the user
   clicks your extension's icon or invokes it through the context menu.
2. The content script adds an invisible iframe that points to `iframe.html` file exposed in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/)
3. The `iframe.html` loads `iframe.js` which uses XMLHttpRequest as usual. Since the iframe has `chrome-extension://` URL its environment
   is the same as your old background script so you can do everything
   you did before right there.

#### Workaround 3. Extension window/tab, Chrome 91+

An alternative solution is to use any other visible page of your
extension like the `action` popup or options page or any other
chrome-extension:// page belonging to your extension as they can
access the `file://` URL via XMLHttpRequest same as before.

#### Notes

- File access should be enabled in `chrome://extensions` page for this extension.

Comment: Sorry, none of this worked, see my edit to question.

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks a lot for the help with getting it through.

Comment: `fetch` supports `file://` scheme since Chrome 99.