# Why does @require always give me the error "couldn't load @require from forbidden URL" for local scripts on Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey on MacOS

Tags: google-chrome-extension, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I like to keep my personal userscripts on local storage that syncs to the cloud. What I have been doing in the past is simply backing them up but then I realized I can use the `@require` tag to link to my local version of the file which I can then edit in my IDE.

This worked for a while but stopped working for some reason about 2 years ago and I would like to solve this issue as I am using userscripts more and more these days.

I'm using `Google Chrome`, `Tampermonkey` and `MacOS`.

Here is an example of my userscript code. Please be advised that I'm certain the path is correct.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google Mods
// @run-at       document-start
// @namespace    http://google.com/
// @version      1.00
// @description  Google mods
// @author       John Doe
// @match        https://*.google.com/*
// @require      file://⁨/Users/johndoe/Desktop/google.user.js
// ==/UserScript==
```

When I look at the console when viewing the page I can tell that it is attempting to load the script but cannot find it. This is what the error looks like

> Tampermonkey: couldn't load @require from forbidden URL file://⁨/Users/johndoe/Desktop/google.user.js

Any help as to what I am missing would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: To be clear I have the extension setting `Allow access to file URLs` enabled.

Comment: You need to enable `file access` checkbox on chrome://extensions page in Tampermonkey's details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am certain that I have that check. I'll edit my original post to clarify.

Comment: So the error is thrown by Tampermonkey which means you also need to allow file access in Tampermonkey's settings. For example I see "Allow scripts to access local files" when switching TM to advanced mode.

Answer (score 3):

1. Type in the chrome search bar: **chrome://extensions**.
2. Then search for: **Tampermonkey**.
3. When you find the tampermonkey extension **click on details**.
4. Navigate almost to the end and enable the option: **allow access to file urls**.

I hope it helps, greetings

[image: search tampermonkey]
[image: enable the option to allow URLs]

Answer (score 1):

By default, extensions in modern browsers do not have access to local file system for security reasons. Therefore, the userscript manager will not be able to load `file://⁨/Users/johndoe/Desktop/google.user.js`

Greasemonkey is a Firefox extension and on Firefox there is no option to allow file system access.

As explained by wOxxOm, on Tampermonkey for Chrome it is possible to allow access to allow [access to local file URIs](https://www.tampermonkey.net/faq.php#Q204).

More info: [Chrome extension - how to access local file:// with manifest v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66245298/chrome-extension-how-to-access-local-file-with-manifest-v3)

Comment: Chrome extensions can do it (and always could) after the user manually enabled file access on chrome://extensions page in extension's details.

Comment: @wOxxOm The post has Greasemonkey tag which is Firefox extension so I thought the poster is looking for a universal solution.

Comment: The tag was added incorrectly judging by the contents of the question so the answer is incorrect too since it doesn't address the user's main case - Tampermonkey. You can fix it by describing that userscript extensions for Chrome in general can access files and how to configure Tampermonkey to allow file access.