# how can i open chrome://apps url by local tab?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

recently i create my own custom chrome home and newTab page
and add anchor tag with tihs url "chrome://apps" to open app tab in chrome,
but it's not working. with error msg -(local url not allowed) so i tried Javascript functions like
ulr replace
window location
and more
but none of these option work
please solve my problem

Comment: What do you mean by "local tab"?

Comment: Note that (as far as I know), _all_ URIs using the `chrome://` scheme (e.g. `chrome://apps`, `chrome://flags`, `chrome://version`, etc) cannot be navigated to nor requested (via `fetch` or XHR) from a non-`chrome://` page (including local-disk `file:///` pages, public Internet pages, LAN pages, and Chrome Extensions). So... what you're asking is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

if you're doing this through google chrome extensions, you will have to define certain permissions in the manifest file. Take a look at the [permissions rundown](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/) for chrome extensions, as well as this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66245298/chrome-extension-how-to-access-local-file-with-manifest-v3) thread. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no permission or workaround to allow Chrome Extensions to open new tabs (nor reload existing tabs) to any page in the `chrome://` URI scheme (but `chrome-extension://` might work, but only if it's the current/same extension's base URI... I might be wrong, so anyone please correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: you can access `chrome-extension://` for sure, as that's where the assets are, but just `chrome://` I'm not sure myself, however, my extension developing skills are quiet narrow, so, it might be a possibility, hence all the links to more information